# keybinding behavior and smartparens

Tags: key-bindings, smartparens

I am using a german keyboard layout and because it is very annoying to type curly brackets I have remapped them to `C-7` and `C-0` in addition to the default binding `AltGr-7` and `AltGr-0`. I also want to modify the behavior of smartparens for cpp-mode and there is already a code snippet in the smartparens [documentation](https://smartparens.readthedocs.io/en/latest/permissions.html#pre-and-post-action-hooks) which does exactly what I want. When I type  `{` and press `Return` it immediately creates and empty line between the curly brackets and moves the pointer to that empty line with an indent. But it does so only when I use `AltGr-7` and press `Return` but not when I used `C-7` and press `Return` (it just inserts a new line). Is it possible to make smartparens behave with `C-7` like it would with `AltGr-7`?

Code snippets I am referring too:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-7") (kbd "{"))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-0") (kbd "}"))

(use-package smartparens
  :hook
  (prog-mode . smartparens-mode)
  (c++-mode . smartparens-mode)
  :config (require 'smartparens-config)
  )

;; From smartparens documentation  
(sp-local-pair 'c++-mode "{" nil :post-handlers '((my-create-newline-and-enter-sexp "RET")))

(defun my-create-newline-and-enter-sexp (&rest _ignored)
  "Open a new brace or bracket expression, with relevant newlines and indent. "
  (newline)
  (indent-according-to-mode)
  (forward-line -1)
  (indent-according-to-mode))
```